# Animation: Drawing vector circle

Tags: android, animation

#### Problem Description

I want to animate vector image.
It should be simple animation, like drawing circle from scratch.

#### Source Code

```
<vector android:height="24dp" android:viewportHeight="20.0"
    android:viewportWidth="20.0" android:width="24dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="#000000"
        android:pathData="M10,0C4.5,0 0,4.5 0,10C0,15.5 4.5,20 10,20C15.5,20 20,15.5 20,10C20,4.5 15.5,0 10,0L10,0ZM10,18C5.6,18 2,14.4 2,10C2,5.6 5.6,2 10,2C14.4,2 18,5.6 18,10C18,14.4 14.4,18 10,18L10,18Z"
        android:strokeColor="#00000000" android:strokeWidth="1"/>
</vector>
```

[image][image][image]
[image]

Comment: http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2016/11/introduction-to-icon-animation-techniques.html

Comment: @0X0nosugar thanks, but can you please post a code to how animate exactly my drawable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code is inspired by Alex J. Lockwood's blog on [Icon Animation Techniques](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2016/11/introduction-to-icon-animation-techniques.html), especially his implementation of an indeterminate `ProgressBar`.

While adapting it to draw a red circle, I ran into some problems. For example it is still not possible to use `aapt:attr` in Android Studio, but as a workaround one can put the code in separate files (see below). 
Another problem is that the stroke width of the path looks smaller while the animation is running compared to the same path after the animation has ended. You can test this by exchanging

```
    android:repeatCount="-1"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
```

for

```
    android:repeatCount="0"
```

My really hacky workaround for this would be to put another `View` with just a white circle as background and a width and height of 48dp on top of the `ImageView` with the red circle.

So here's how to (repeatedly) draw a circle:

The circle (res/drawable/circle_48dp):

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="48dp"
    android:height="48dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path   
        android:name="redCircle"
        android:fillColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:strokeColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:strokeLineCap="square"
        android:strokeLineJoin="miter"
        android:strokeWidth="4"
    android:pathData="M12,2C6.47,2 2,6.47 2,12s4.47,10 10,10 10,-4.47 10,-10S17.53,2 12,2zM12,20c-4.41,0 -8,-3.59 -8,-8s3.59,-8 8,-8 8,3.59 8,8 -3.59,8 -8,8z"/>
</vector>
```

The animation (res/animator/trim_path)

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="1333"
        android:propertyName="trimPathStart"
        android:repeatCount="-1"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:valueFrom="1.00"
        android:valueTo="0.0"
        android:valueType="floatType"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
    </objectAnimator>
</set>
```

The animated vector drawable (res/drawable/avd_circle)

```
<animated-vector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/circle_48dp">

    <target android:name="redCircle" 
        android:animation="@animator/trim_path">
    </target>
</animated-vector>
```

The `Activity` layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.vectordrawables.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Animated Circle"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_animated_circle"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/avd_circle"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And, finally, how to start the animation in `onCreate()`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ((Animatable)((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_animated_circle)).getDrawable()).start();
}
```

Comment: its not easy to draw circle and understand its path : android:pathData="M12,2C6.47,2 2,6.47 2,12s4.47,10 10,10 10,-4.47 10,-10S17.53,2 12,2zM12,20c-4.41,0 -8,-3.59 -8,-8s3.59,-8 8,-8 8,3.59 8,8 -3.59,8 -8,8z"/>

Comment: @Tushar Pandey - you got that right, it's far from easy. I suppose there are tools available to help you with generating vector drawables but unfortunately I'm not familiar with any of them. The path for this post is taken from a VectorDrawable generated by AndroidStudio which I changed to get just the circle (ic_error_outline_black_24dp.xml without "M11,15h2v2h-2zM11,7h2v6h-2z" at the beginning)

Comment: If you want to generate a vector drawable, you can even don't understand paths at all. Just create a SVG (using Adobe Illustrator or such a program) and then convert it to a vector drawable (using an online site, such as http://inloop.github.io/svg2android)